Combine dissolve aggfunc and lambda function
I am looking to aggregate different polygons and applies analytical functions at the same time.
I have tried:
df.dissolve(by=['ville','arrondissement','quartier'], 
aggfunc={'transaction':'count','psqm':'median' }).reset_index().rename(columns ={'transaction':'TotalTransac'})

How can I add the lambda function to the aggregation while keep everything in one line?
For instance I am looking to compute the quantile of psqm as follows:
'psqm':lambda x: x.quantile(0.25) 


You can use the .axis parameter to tell pandas to calculate quantile column-wise:
df.dissolve(by="region", aggfunc={"transactions":"count", "psqm":["count", lambda x: x.quantile(0.25, axis=1)]}, as_index=False).rename(columns={('transactions', 'count'):"transaction_count", ('psqm', 'count'): "psqm_count", ('psqm', '<lambda_0>'): "psqm_quantile"})

